# Bootstrap 4 Card with dynamic header and fixed body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap 4 card:

```
<div class="card" style="height:"500px;width:100px">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="top-portion">
        This portion can span from one to many lines.
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="overflow-y">
        ....
        ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the ".content" div to occupy the remaining vertical space and be scrollable when needed. I know that I am supposed to put "max-height:..." at its style.

However, the problem is that I do not know the exact value to put because the ".top-portion" section varies in height.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="card" style="height:500px; width:100px;overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="top-portion mb-auto">
              This portion can span from one to many lines.
          </div>
          <div class="content" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height: 200px;">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

use this code for your card. and "top-portion" height never disturb content. I have use "mb-auto" it means margin-bottom:auto; if you want to put content area bottom of card.

Comment: 'max-height: 200px;' is a fixed value. the problem is that I don't want it to be fixed.

Comment: Also you can use max-height:100%. And height:auto, if its won't work than use align-self: bottom nd height:auto. But scroll only work when you consider height as well.